# Проблема с заморозкой цикла

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность, multiprocessing

Суть вопроса в следующем - функция main постоянно проверяет базу данных на предмет изменения значений. Далее при определённом условии должна запускать функцию logic. Она её запускает, но в тот же момент идёт заморозка цикла while true. Как сделать игнорирование await и при выполнении условия не замораживать цикл, а запустить функцию и дальше проверять бд по циклу?

P.S. Функция logic обязательно должна быть async, т.к. там используется pyrogram

```
     async def main():
        logger.info('')
        dbase.until_start_bot()
        in_process = list()
        while True:
            result = dbase.search_in_queue()
            if result is not None:
                ignoring_flag = False
                for res in in_process:
                    if res == result[1]:
                        ignoring_flag = True
    
                if not ignoring_flag:
                    in_process.append(result[1])
                    await logic(result)
                else:
                    pass

    async def logic(result):
         """Continue"""
        pass
```

Comment: А если просто убрать await?

Comment: logic подразумевает использование асинхронных библиотек. Не получится. Там используется pyrogram

Comment: а что если стандартно сделать while n<нужное количество прохождений while и в самом while после каждого прохождения +1

Comment: Нужное количество прохождений while неизвестно. Оно не ограничено, выполняется пока работает софт. Такой своеобразный демон, который проверяет постоянно

Comment: len() туда никак не прицепить?

Comment: Никак, в базу постоянно добавляются значения постоянно

Comment: Тут проблема именно в остановке на моменте запуска logic и функцию logic нужно запускать без остановки цикла while true, т.е. игнорировать await. Пробовали запускать её в asyncio.create_task multiprocessing, threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если цикл должен продолжаться, вы можете использовать внутри `logic()` бэкграунд-задачу. Как пример, запустить в отдельном треде:

```
from threading import Thread

def some_func(in_process):
    ...
    # в конце удалить результат из in_process

async def logic(in_process):
    t = Thread(target=some_func, args=[in_process])
    t.start()
```

Нужно следить за проблемами конкурентности. Например, продумать, что произойдет, если следующая таска запустится до завершения предыдущей.

Comment: Но модуль thread не позволяет запустить в себе async функцию. Функция logic является продолжением и вызывается по условию и является async.

Comment: А нельзя запустить внутри logic() тред? Он неблокирующий, и logic() подумает, что она отработала, а тред продолжит выполнение.

Comment: Тут не меняет сути дела, т.к. в функции logic используется библиотека pyrogram и в любом случае функция, которая должна отработать в thread должна быть async

Comment: Такой формат реализации был попробован в первую очередь, результат отрицательный. Упираемся в потребность запуска async функции в отдельном потоке или процессе, а там он работать корректно и запускаться отказывается

Comment: Понял. Возможно, имеет смысл сделать отделный event_loop. Один проверяет базу и складывает задачи в очередь, второй разгребает очередь и выполняет таски. Но пример уже не напишу: не знаю специфики pyrogram.

Comment: Импульсивность мою надо мне убирать, я зациклился на одной попытке решения и не смог сначала понять Вашу мысль. Так, как вы описали работает. Сделал по принципу:
- Запуск функции main и проверка в цикле
-- Если условие выполнено запускаю logic
--- Из logic запускаю новый поток с циклом для проверки
---- Старый цикл после ожидания await убиваю

Comment: О, шикарно! Поздравляю с решением 